# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') in React

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

```
import DesktopDatePicker from "@mui/lab/DesktopDatePicker";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import { Grid, TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

const [incomeRecord, setIncomeRecord] = useState({
    date: new Date(),
    shopSales: "",
    payPoint: "",
});

   <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
        label="Date"
        inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={incomeRecord.date}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setIncomeRecord({ ...incomeRecord, date: e.target.value })
        }
        renderInput={(incomeRecord) => <TextField {...incomeRecord} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>

  <TextField
      className="txtlabel"
      variant="outlined"
      label="Shop Sales"
      value={incomeRecord.shopSales}
      onChange={(e) =>
        setIncomeRecord({ ...incomeRecord, shopSales: e.target.value })
      }
    ></TextField>
```

How can I get the date to the text field. Error appear when running the code. I need to know how to get value entering from date picker to text field.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get the value from `document.getElementsByClassName`

```
getElementsByClassName("txtlabel").value
```

let me know if it work or we can do some changes to the code

thank's
Mohamad